# Which ANOVA is most appropriate?

Tags: anova, mixed-model

So, I have a question for a proposal and I'm fairly certain I'm getting an incorrect answer from our local "stats guy". For the record, it's archival data so I can't change the items  (which aren't that well done):

One set of items is looking at the appropriateness of behaviour of two types of professionals (say doctors and nurses) and we are having participants rate the appropriateness of 6 different behaviours. I would like to compare participant responses across all 6 behaviours and in particular, differences between how participants may feel certain behaviours are consistent with certain professions...any idea which methods might be most useful here?

Our "stats guy" suggested a mixed-design ANOVA, but I guess I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how that would be set up. Maybe I could just use clarification for the mixed-design model...

Comment: With all the respect: Do not bad-mouth your colleagues in public. More to the point of your question: from the looks of it, a mixed-effect ANOVA seems like an obvious first choice actually. Your random effect would be your participant ID and your fixed effects your different behaviour types interacting with your professional types at first glance. Try it, see how it goes, post some results and we can take it from there.